# How do I delete a value from an object based on criteria in javaScript

Tags: javascript, object

Why does this code run without errors, but not delete anything from obj?

```js
function removeEvenValues(obj) {
       for (i=0; i < obj.length;++i)
          if (obj[i].value%2===0)
            delete obj[i];
            return obj;
}

const obj = {a:1, b:2 ,c:3, d:4}
const res = removeEvenValues(obj);

console.log(res);
```

Comment: Because the way you are iterating over object is incorrect!!. If your obj is an array then access elements like obj[i].value. To iterate over object use for key in obj

Comment: What is the type of **obj**? from the snippet, it doesn't look like an array and hence you can't loop. Did you mean `if (obj[i].value%2===2)`?

Comment: Please edit the question to include an example of `obj` it's really difficult to help if we don't know what that looks like.

Comment: Your obj is not avid javascript. Is it supposed to be: `obj ={a:1,b:2,c:3,d:4}`?

Comment: sorry, coming from python...

Comment: It doesn't make any sense.

array = [1,2,3]
object = {a:1,b:2,c:3}

this is the notation in javascript.

So your type of your obj is an Object, not an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike Python you can't just iterate the length of an object because `obj.length === undefined`. You can use `Object.keys()` to get an array of keys. Then you can iterate them:

```js
obj = {a:1,b:2,c:3,d:4}

function removeEvenValues(obj) {
       Object.keys(obj).forEach(key =>{
        if (obj[key] % 2 ===0)
            delete obj[key];
       })  
       return obj;
}

console.log(removeEvenValues(obj))
```

or you can also use `for...in`:

```js
obj = {a:1,b:2,c:3,d:4}

function removeEvenValues(obj) {
   for(let key in obj){
     if (obj[key] % 2 ===0)
         delete obj[key];
     }
     return obj
}

console.log(removeEvenValues(obj))
```

Comment: Is `for (i = 0; i < obj.length; ++i)` not a preferred method anymore in jS?

Comment: @Guar `for` loops are fine. The problem is that objects don't have a length. `obj.length === undefined`.